# Simplify logic statement

Tags: if-statement, boolean-operations

I have this:

```
if(!A or (A and B))   //pseudocode
```

I want to *negate* that if-statement:

This should work:

```
if(!(!A or (A and B)))  //pseudocode
```

but I believe there is a way to simplify it and it's escaping me at the moment.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28NOT+A+OR+%28A+AND+B%29%29

Comment: @suraj that's wrong because that reduces to simply if(A)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to the world of de-Morgan for boolean algebra followed by simple distribution :

```
if(!(!A or (A and B)) 
=> if(!(!A) and !(A and B))
=> if(A and (!A or !B))
=> if((A and !A) or (A and !B))
=> if(A and !B)
```

Comment: thanks this seems to gel with the output of wolfram alpha

Answer (score 4):

If you break it down to a truth table...

```
A B  !A  (A and B)  A! or (A and B)
0 0  1   0          1
0 1  1   0          1
1 0  0   0          0
1 1  0   1          1
```

You can see the result is true in all cases except `A and !B` without having to know/remember any Boolean algebra rules. "Except" is just "not" so... `!(A and !B)`...

However if writing `!A or (A and B)` aligns better to the real-world problem you're trying to code leave it like that, unless it's insanely performance critical...